# How to get rid of setlocale warnings during deploy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, unix, capistrano

I get a lot of warnings during deploy

```
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (pl_PL.UTF-8)
```

`pl_PL.UTF-8` is my local locale system

How to get rid of that warnings?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the server is missing the pl_PL locale that your client is trying to use to connect to the server.

Try the following commands on server:

```
sudo locale-gen pl_PL
sudo update-locale LANG=pl_PL
```

Comment: I don't have an sudo rights on server and I would like to keep servers locale as default what is it

Comment: hm.. then you can try to add `export LC_ALL="pl_PL.UTF-8"` in `~/.bash_profile`

Comment: Capistrano won't source dotfiles, see http://www.capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue running Capistrano through Vagrant, except mine was "cannot change locale (en_US)". Finally got rid of this message. Here's what I did:

```
sudo nano /etc/profile
```

add the following lines

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

then modify this file

```
sudo nano /etc/skel/.bashrc
```

add these lines

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

then logoff and log back in and the messages should be gone.